# horizontal line width using \xhline

Tags: tables

So I've been using `\Xhline` in my tables so that I can set the top, second and bottom line of the tables thicker than the rest. My code (below) works and produces a table and the top and bottom lines have increased in thickness but for some reason the second hasn't even though I've used the exact same command. The code beneath is just for my table, the rest of the document is huge. When I copy this section of code into a new window and run it the table looks perfect, but when I run it in my main document the line thickness doesn't always increase. Does anyone know what might be causing it to intermittently work in my document?

p.s couldn't tag `xhline` or `hline` hence only including the table tag.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{8.5cm}}
\Xhline{2.0pt}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Model set-up}} \\
\Xhline{2.0pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Channel dimensions}} & 29.76m x 2m\\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Bathymetry}} & 8m$<$x$<$12m & Z\textsubscript{f} = 0.05 * (x - 10) \textsuperscript{2}\\ 
& Everywhere else: & Z\textsubscript{f} = -0.2m \\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Mesh (Figure XXXX)}} & Triangulated regular grid. Increased resolution at the bump and it is wake. \\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Boundaries}}} 
      & Channel entrance: Open boundary with prescribed discharge ($Q$ = 2m\textsuperscript{3}) \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} 
      & Channel exit: Open boundary with prescribed water level ($y$=0.4m)\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} 
      & Remaining boundaries: Closed \\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Friction}} & Bottom friction was defined using the Strickler formula and a coefficient of 40 was set. All other sides were frictionless\\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Time step}} & 0.02 seconds\\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Duration}} & 100 seconds\\ \Xhline{0.2pt}
\Xhline{2.0pt}
\end{tabular}
\centering
\end {table}

\end {document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not show your error. Please reduce this table to a minimum and than start trying around, which macro or which packages is causing the error for you. Like this, we cannot help, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your table with much less packages in use. I left the line thicknesses as wished by you, but defined this rules just with `booktabs`. Maybe this works for you:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{8.5cm}} \toprule[2.0pt]
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Model set-up}} \\ \midrule[2.0pt]
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Channel dimensions}} & $\SI{29.76}{\metre}\times\SI{2}{\metre}$ \\ \midrule[0.2pt]
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Bathymetry}} & $\SI{8}{\metre}<x<\SI{12}{\metre}$ & $Z_\mathrm{f} = 0.05\cdot(x-10)^2$\\ & Everywhere else: & $Z_\mathrm{f}= \SI{-0.2}{\metre}$ \\ \midrule[0.2pt]
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Mesh (Figure XXXX)}}} & Triangulated regular grid. Increased resolution at the bump and it is wake. \\ \midrule[0.2pt]
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Boundaries}}} & Channel entrance: Open boundary with prescribed discharge ($Q = \SI{2}{\cubic\metre}$) \\ 
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{} & Channel exit: Open boundary with prescribed water level ($y=\SI{0.4}{\metre}$)\\
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{} & Remaining boundaries: Closed \\ \midrule[0.2pt]
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Friction}}} & Bottom friction was defined using the Strickler formula and a coefficient of $40$ was set. All other sides were frictionless\\ \midrule[0.2pt]
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Time step}} & $0.02$ seconds \\ \midrule[0.2pt]
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Duration}} & $100$ seconds \\ \bottomrule[2.0pt]
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks yes that would work for what im doing. Also found out that the problem was to do with the pdf viewer not the code.